# How to dynamize column alias from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the bellow query ,i'm looking for to dynamize column name label from another table.
In table #Tmp2 the Dim1 change depending Dim1.Num for exemple i can have
for `Dim1.Num = 1 => Dim1 =BusinessUnit`
in other cas i can hav `Dim1.Num = 1 => Dim1 =Department`

```
SELECT Dim1.Dim1 ,Dim1.ValueDim1  ,
       Dim2.Dim2 ,Dim2.ValueDim2  ,
       #Tmp1.Amount

INTO   #Tmp3

FROM   #Tmp1

INNER JOIN #Tmp2 as Dim1 on Dim1.id = #Tmp1.id And Dim1.Num=1
INNER JOIN #Tmp2 as Dim2 on Dim1.id = #Tmp1.id And Dim2.Num=2
```

This is the result :

```
Dim1            ValueDim1  Dim2         ValueDim2  Amount
BusinessUnit    002        Department   027        1000
```

But i want this result

```
BusinessUnit    ValueDim1  Department   ValueDim2  Amount
BusinessUnit    002        Department   027        1000
```

That is, depending on what value of `#Tmp2.Num`, the applicable name of the column can change.

mybe somthing like this

```
SELECT Dim1.Dim1 AS (select Dim from #Tmp2 where #Tmp2.Num = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(20) = (select Dim from #Tmp2 where #Tmp2.Num = 1)

EXEC('SELECT Dim1.Dim1 ['+@ColName+'] ,Dim1.ValueDim1  ,
       Dim2.Dim2 ,Dim2.ValueDim2  ,
       #Tmp1.Amount

INTO   #Tmp3

FROM   #Tmp1

INNER JOIN #Tmp2 as Dim1 on Dim1.id = #Tmp1.id And Dim1.Num=1
INNER JOIN #Tmp2 as Dim2 on Dim1.id = #Tmp1.id And Dim2.Num=2')
```

The limitations with this (and your question in general) is that if your `#Tmp2` has two records with the same `Num`, then the query will throw a `Subquery returned more than one value` error. The only way to get around this is to change your @ColName query so it only ever returns a single value:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(20) = (select TOP 1 Dim from #Tmp2 where #Tmp2.Num = 1)
```

**Update:**

If it's possible that your query to get the column name can return 0 records, then modify your query as follows:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(20) = (
    select Dim from #Tmp2 where #Tmp2.Num = 1 
    UNION 
    SELECT 'DefaultValue' WHERE NOT EXISTS (select Dim from #Tmp2 where #Tmp2.Num = 1)
    )
```

However, if your query returns a record but the value in the Column you want to use as the Column Name is null, then modify the query like so:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(20) = (select ISNULL(Dim,'DefaultValue') from #Tmp2 where #Tmp2.Num = 1)
```

Comment: I look that i have one problem, somtimes i have  @ColName null, so i must do somthing like : Dim7.Dim7.FinalValue        AS CASE
                  WHEN Dim7.FinalValue = '' THEN
                   Dim7
                  ELSE 
                   ['+@Dim7+'] 
                 END